# iOS - stop UIRefreshControl on push up

Tags: ios, uitableview, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer, uirefreshcontrol

I've recently implemented `UIRefreshControl` to load data from iCloud when pulled down, however, I find it intuitive for user to push the `UITableView` back up when he demands to stop refreshing. I am not able to figure out how to detect this without using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which would then remove the functionality of my `UITableView`.

Is there any way I can detect pushing the `UITableView` back up during refresh, without removing functionality of existing tableview? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do in this situation is to take advantage of the fact that a UITableViewDelegate conforms to the UIScrollViewDelegate. That way you can figure out when different scrolling events occur on your tableView. If you are a subclass of a UITableViewController, you already conform to the UITableViewDelegate, so you're all good there.

The first thing I did was to have a property for the contentOffset so that I can record it when the dragging is starting.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *contentOffsetAtStartOfDragging;
```

The reason I chose to make this a NSNumber instead of say a CGFloat which may seem more natural, is because I don't want that property stuck with some value when it's not needed. When  that property is no longer useful to me, I want it to be nil. That's just my design choice though, it wouldn't really make any difference.

Anyway, the way I did this was to record that contentOffset when the dragging is starting, and then comparing that to the contentOffset when the dragging ended. That was I know if the user has been scrolling to a contentOffset that is lower than what it was at the start of the dragging, and I can end the refreshing.

Also when the dragging is done, I set my property to nil for the reason explained above.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ([self.refreshControl isRefreshing]) {
        self.contentOffsetAtStartOfDragging = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:scrollView.contentOffset.y];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if ([self.refreshControl isRefreshing] &&
        scrollView.contentOffset.y > [self.contentOffsetAtStartOfDragging floatValue])
    {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }

    self.contentOffsetAtStartOfDragging = nil;
}
```

Hope this was helpful. Let me know if it worked out for you.

Comment: Thank you.

I used part of your suggestion and it worked perfectly. I only tracked the end of dragging, and if the refreshing was happening, I checked how low did the swipe go and if low enough, I would stop refreshing. Here's the code.

`- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if([refreshNotes isRefreshing] && scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [refreshNotes endRefreshing];
    }
}`

Comment: Yes, that certainly works as well. Only difference is that now the user has to swipe all the way up to stop the refreshing. There are pros and cons for both ways of doing it I suppose. With my way the user don't have to scroll all the way, but they could trigger it unintentionally. With your way the user has to give a little more effort, but it will almost always be intentional. I guess it's a design choice you have to make.